# DB2 Create Table if not exists without columns

Tags: sql, db2

how is the simplest way to test if some column exists in DB2?
i am just trying to run a script that add a column. I don't want a procedure.
It is necessery to use Begin End or create a procedure?

```
IF (NOT EXISTS(
SELECT * FROM P1ADM549.T549RMOP WHERE VR_PGO ='VR_PGO' AND COLNAME = 'VR_PGO'))
THEN
    EXECUTE something...
END
```

Comment: Why did you tagged as sql-server?

Comment: I don't understand why in 2020 there's still no functional IF NOT EXISTS statement for DB2 or why anyone would work with DB2. It's torture if you're used to modern databases. In sane SQL you would simply use `ALTER TABLE wave ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS hello varchar(5);` and go on with your day without the migraine.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a continue handler that "swallows" 42711:

```
#> db2 "create table t1 ( x int )"
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

#> db2 "begin DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '42711' BEGIN END; EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter table t1 add column y int'; end"
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

#> db2 "begin DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '42711' BEGIN END; EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter table t1 add column y int'; end"
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
```

Comment: I used this in "read from file" mode (db2 -vtf filename.sql) and what in this case was important is to put correct sqlstate and hold wrapped "alter/create/drop" statement in one single line.

Comment: Robert, it is better to use other stmt terminator's than ";" because ";" has a special meaning in compound statements, triggers, procedures and so forth. To use @ as a terminator use -td@ -f ...  Not sure what you mean by "put correct sqlstate" in this context, it is always important to use the correct sqlstate in continue handlers

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you can't use `IF .. ELSE` construct in normal SQL; you will have to include your `IF .. ELSE` condition inside a stored routine (procedure or function).

In your case, if `EXECUTE something` part is meant to executing a `SQL` query then probably you can use `NOT EXISTS` in your `WHERE` condition. Something like below but needs more clarification from your end.

```
your_select_query
where not exists
(
SELECT 1 
FROM P1ADM549.T549RMOP 
WHERE VR_PGO ='VR_PGO' 
AND COLNAME = 'VR_PGO')
```

Comment: I just want to add a column if it does not exist, I need to run a script, it is necessary to creaty a function so.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Yes, include your `IF` condition in a procedure and execute a `ALTER` statement accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

DB2 provides the ANSI standard INFORMATION_SCHEMA views so you can check for existence of a column with the technique below.  I'm more of a T-SQL than a DB2 guy so you might need to tweak the control flow statements.

```
IF NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT * 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE
        TABLE_SCHEMA = 'P1ADM549'
        AND TABLE_NAME = 'T549RMOP'
        AND COLUMN_NAME = 'VR_PGO'
    )
BEGIN
    --do something
END;
```

Comment: INFORMATION_SCHEMA is not available in DB2 LUW.

Comment: @AngocA, thanks for the info.  The INFORMATION_SCHEMA objects are available in DB2 for iSeries so it's odd that IBM doesn't provide them in LUW like the other major DBMS products.

Answer (score 0):

In DB2 you have two option, that you can even combine:

First, you can define the `IF ELSE` in a anonymous block, which is defined by BEGIN END

```
BEGIN
 DECLARE EXIST BOOLEAN;
 IF (EXIST = TRUE) THEN
  ...
 ELSE
  ...
 END IF;
END @
```

More info at: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/SQLTips4DB2LUW/entry/anonymous_block?lang=en

The second thing you can do is exploit the capabilities of condition compilation. However, you have to define the CC_FLAGS and this is more for scripting (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/c0056403.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0%2F2-12-7-3)